# Работа с ответом от сервера после POST запроса

Tags: android, post, запрос

Доброго времени суток, при разработке android приложения столкнулся с рядом проблем касающихся POST запросов. большую часть их я решил сам и при помощи этого сайта.
И вот когда уже казалось все сделано, появилась еще одна проблема, а именно после того как я получаю ответ от сервера после POST запроса.
Ответ имеет вид цифры от 0 до 23, то ничего кроме вывода на экран я с ним сделать не могу.
Получаю ответ от сервера таким образом:

```
String bTime = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

или также работает такой метод:

```
bTime = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
//......
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);// + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Я пытался сравнить полученный String с другим Stringом функцией .equals(str), но ничего не произошло, сравнение всегда ложно , пытался превратить String в int функцией  int BeginTime = Integer.parseInt(bTime.toString()) , Integer.parseInt(bTime), int Time = Integer.valueOf(bTime.toString()), Integer.valueOf(bTime) , но при попытке преобразовать строку в число приложение выкидывало с ошибкой.

Таким образом у меня есть ответ от сервера, но я с ним ничего не могу сделать, кроме вывода на экран.
Прошу подсказать что делать и как, в итоге я хотел использовать этот ответ чтобы можно было к нему применить функцию сравнения на равенство с другой цифрой.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что за ошибка при парсе в число? Может всякие скрытые символы всё портят(пробел, пренос строки и т.д.)?

Comment: я отправляю ответом просто число таким образом echo($daybegin) , где $daybegin = 3
при парсе такая ошибка java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.ServiceGPS: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '?3' as integer
не пойму откуда этот знак вопроса так как при выводе на экран его нет , есть только цифра 3. также его нет при показе ошибки в самом eclips, появился после сохранения лога ошибки как файла, если надо могу скинуть весь файл лога.

Comment: символ непечатный, поэтому вы его не видите. логируйте `response.getEntity().getContentLength()`. поставьте breakpoint в эклипсе перед конвертацией, смотрите что у вас в bTime в нулевом символе. Из php лезет мусор, видимо.

Comment: В качестве заплатки убейте регекспом из ответа сервера все "не числа"  :-) Но вообще надо продебажиться откуда оно лезет. Может в php что случайно попалось...какойнить перевод строки и т.д...

Comment: @Чад а точнее скажи, а лучше покажи как использовать регексп этот, я в java новичок большой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать как то так:

```
Integer.parseInt(bTime.replaceAll("([^0-9])","");
```

Насчёт регекспа не уверен на все сто.

Comment: ппц. а если логи полезут и мы их так порежем? в итоге пользователь получит "ваш заказ на 200720123 рублей отправлен". кул.

Comment: Ну логи в принципе не так надо... Надо или уж по человечески обрабатывать ошибки сервера или бить в бубен :)

Comment: Надо прежде всего с серваком разобраться, чтоб работал как положено. функция получения текста ответа верная, значит бажит php. лечить последствия - мертвому припарки.

Comment: Вот я и говорю: **'В качестве заплатки убейте регекспом'**

Comment: Спасибо заплатка помогла)
Пока пусть будет так, но начну смотреть пхп и искать ошибку.